# Voice calling in local network and without network on flutter app

Tags: flutter, local, p2p

I want to make a voice chat room application without an internet connection with Flutter. For example, two people will connect to the same network and when they enter the application, they will be able to talk to each other instantly. Since it will be over LAN, I think it will also work without internet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jvbLhDxek4

I watched this video and I don't know how I can send audio to it instantly.

Comment: webrtc might work for you, you can checkout [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App)

Comment: How can I send an audio file as a stream over a local network without internet using webrtc?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC ellows to establish the peer-to-peer communication but it still needs a server for signaling: to enable the exchange of media and network metadata to bootstrap a peer connection.

So the main problem here is that you need to exchange the “offer” and “answer” between endpoints somehow, so each party will have enough information about each other. Normally, some signaling protocol + public server is used for this purpose.

In your case, you have 3 choices:

- to setup a direct p2p WebSocket connection between 2 devices. Not sure if it's possible.
- manually copy\past the 'offer' and 'answer' SDP, which is not good as well I think
- have some 3rd computer with some signaling server installed, so others peers will use it to exchange the 'offer' and 'answer' between each other.

We have a [P2P Calls sample](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-flutter-samples/tree/master/p2p_call_sample), but here we use the Chat server to excange the offer/answer packagess and additional signaling.